# I set a specific price target for my strategy.exit but when that level is reached nothing happens

Tags: pine-script

As the title suggests, I have a working strategy tester that enters and exits positions, mostly, on point with what I've set.

This tester includes two confirmation indicators that need to converge for proper entry.

But there are some inconsistencies that I cannot explain.

I've set a take profit and stop loss level for every potential candle entry and you can see this represented by the plotted green and red line(representing tp and sl respectively.)

I'm using valuewhen() to target the specific candle that met my entryLong conditions.

I've attached two images of my code properly working and it not working respectively.

I've also included my current code.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

//====================// LONG ENTRY \====================\

```
//long conditions

longCondition1 = bBullTrend and c1LongSignal

longCondition2 = bLongSignal and c1BullTrend


//long entry

longEntry = longCondition1 or longCondition2


//open long position

if dateRange

if closeDistanceFromBaseline < atr

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty = totalPosition, when = longEntry)


//exit long conditions

exitLongTP = valuewhen(longEntry, longProfit, 0)

exitLongSL = valuewhen(longEntry, longLoss, 0)


longTPTarget = high >= exitLongTP


//exit long position


if longTPTarget

strategy.exit("Long TP", "Long", limit = exitLongTP, stop = exitLongTP)
```

[image: Proper functionality]

[image: Improper functionality]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `exitLongTP` and `exitLongTP` values not  = `na` when calling `strategy.exit()`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Though, I'm fairly certain it's not returning 'na' since it clearly works on other candles. Idk if this is a bug or if I'm missing specific code somewhere. Anymore insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some compilable code where problem reproducing

Comment: Do you want my entire strategy code? or the snippet that's returning these inconsitencies?

Comment: Do you want my entire strategy code? or the snippet that's returning these inconsistencies? this part:( longEntry = longCondition1 or longCondition2) initiates when price and the indicator I'm uses crosses over to signify a longEntry.

This part :(exitLongTP = valuewhen(longEntry, longProfit, 0)) stores the value of the take profit level when the longEntry expression became true. But I'm afraid that the value keeps getting updated as the candles progress and theinitial take profit level is lost.